# Display a node in Views, but disable the node page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm creating a "Testimonials" block with a new content type and Views module. The problem is that Drupal creates a separate page for each testimonial and users could access the page should they know its ID (or find the page in SERP).

Is it possible to disable node pages for that specific content type, but list the nodes in a Views block? The standard "404" Drupal page would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky one because you're not going to be able to use [hook_node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) (the view mode is never passed through so you can't determine between teaser and full pages). A quick dirty way to do it would be in [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7):

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_node_type' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    drupal_not_found();
  }
}
```

There are probably better mode 'Drupal' ways to do it but that will do in a pinch.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that now there is no way to edit testimonial nodes because links from the "Find content" page lead to 404 pages.

Comment: OK, I've figured out how to fix this: `if ($node->type == 'my_node_type' && $view_mode == 'full' && !user_access('edit my_node_type')) { drupal_not_found(); }` Now the page is visible to users having enough permissions to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for Drupal 6.x, but it is probably quite similar for Drupal 7...

The [Chaos Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) modules for Drupal can accomplish this. With the Chaos Tools sub module, 'Page Manager', you can enable the 'node_view' page under 'Manage pages...' (Site building -> Pages).

Once the 'node_view' page is enabled, you will add a 'Variant' (e.g. Title: 'Non-Admin User') with 'Selection Rules' and set the criteria to 'Node Type', then limit it to your content type (e.g. Testimonial).

After that, one more 'Selection Rule' will be needed for 'User Role'. With that, choose both the anonymous and authenticated user roles.

Next, continue through the setup and choose a 'Single column' layout, then click the 'gear' icon in the 'Middle column' when choosing your panel's content. You can then specify an existing node (e.g. your 404 node page).

Next, I would recommend setting up another 'Variant' (e.g. Title 'Admin User') on your 'node_view' page with 'Selection Rules' criteria set to your content type and set the user criteria to your administrator role(s) or user id #1. Then instead of adding the 404 node as the content to your panel page, you can add the 'current node being viewed' to the panel content. This way admins can still see the node pages and normal users will be directed to your 404 page.